# restricting .env file from other ssh admin

Tags: ssh, root, .env

so myself, and a guild member of mine, are working ona bot
together for our server. Its first and main purpose was to link our path of exile accounts, with our discord accounts so we can identify members of the discord server and be able to tell who they are in-game. so far we have not  had a problem doing this, or getting this part of the bot running 24/7 via nodejs and pm2.

my first question is, since i am the guild's leader, and the bot is connected to MY DISCORDS DEV portal, it has my discord token in the .env file located in the bot's home folder.
as of rn, i know that the other admin has root access and can see my token. im not really worried about it at this time but who knows what the future may hold. so my question is, there anyway to make the .env file readable by pm2 or npm, but be able to hide my token or any other senstitve information like mongodb login from the other admin? without breaking the whole project becus i made the .env file unreadable?

Pretty much i dont want him to be able to go in and nano ~/poe-discord/.env and be able to see my token. how can i set it up to where the token is unreadable by him

i still need/want him to have full root access tho.
if i set up two accounts , one for me and one for him, both "su" or "root", can i make certain files only readable by certain users?
can i make it pull the .env file from a seperate location that is only accessable by the account who made the file?

im unsure what to try first..

Comment: is this possible? thank you:)